# What is the maximum number of processes that can be used in parallel Stream

Tags: java-8

I know that we can use -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism to set the parallelism, but is there any upper limit to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking into the source code of `ForkJoinPool`, I find the definition of

```
MAX_CAP    = 0x7fff;  // max #workers - 1
```

which is enforced when using the constructor [`ForkJoinPool(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#ForkJoinPool-int-) by throwing an exception when you attempt to specify more. However, when using the system property, `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism` to configure the parallelism of the common pool, you can safely specify more (up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`), it will be silently reduced to the supported maximum then.

Comment: Sorry, as this is not my question. But what kind of things could one do using the above method? Thanks.

Comment: That said, you're probably turning the wrong knob.  This knob is here for *deployers* to manage resource utilization, not for developers to try and tweak the parallelism of specific operations.